# SonarQube 6.7.7 How to add junit test count to dashboard without analysing tests

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube

When I add sonar.tests I get the tests analysed and the number of tests, I only want the number of tests but not the analysis.

sonar-project.properties:

```
sonar.projectKey=xxx

sonar.java.binaries=target/classes
sonar.java.test.binaries=target/test-classes
sonar.sources=src/main/java
sonar.tests=src/test/java
sonar.test.exclusions=src/test/java/**
sonar.java.source=11
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.junit.reportPaths=target/surefire-reports/testng-junit-results/junitreports/
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it. It is impossible.